# iOS Embed Cordova App into another as a webview

Tags: android, ios, swift, cordova, plugins

I have an App that is developed in Cordova at work and now I am being asked to "pluginize" that App to be able to open it from another App which will also be developed in Cordova. To sum it up they want to open an App from another App. In Android I have been able to do this through webviews like this:

- Both Apps are made in Ionic.
- I compiled it to get the `www` folder.
- I copied the `www`folder into the `src` folder of a plugin project.
- For Android I use this code:

  PhonePlugin.java

  ```
  public class PhonePlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

  @Override
  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
      try {
          actionExecutor(action, args);
          callbackContext.success("launched!");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          callbackContext.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
      }

      return true;
  }

  private void actionExecutor(String action, JSONArray args) throws Exception {
      if ("start".equals(action)) {
          JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(args.getString(0));
          final String poi = jsonObject.getString("poi");
          final String email = jsonObject.getString("email");
          final String apikey = jsonObject.getString("apikey");

          cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  start(poi, email, apikey);
              }
          });
      } else if("finish".equals(action)) {
          cordova.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  finish();
              }
          });
      } else {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown action: " + action);
      }
  }

  private void start(String poi, String email, String apikey) {
      Intent intent = new Intent(cordova.getActivity(), PhoneActivity.class);
      intent.putExtra(PhoneActivity.EMAIL, email);
      intent.putExtra(PhoneActivity.APIKEY, apikey);
      intent.putExtra(PhoneActivity.POI, poi);

      cordova.getActivity().startActivity(intent);
      cordova.getActivity().overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
  }

  private void finish() {
      cordova.getActivity().finish();
  }}
  ```

PhoneActivity.java

```
public class PhoneActivity extends CordovaActivity {
    public static String POI = "POI";
    public static String EMAIL = "EMAIL";
    public static String APIKEY = "APIKEY";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();

        String poi = getIntent().getStringExtra(POI);
        String email = getIntent().getStringExtra(EMAIL);
        String apikey = getIntent().getStringExtra(APIKEY);

        String indexUrl = "file:///android_asset/www/phoneplugin/index.html?poi=" + poi + "&apikey=" + apikey + "&email=" + email;
        loadUrl(indexUrl);
    }

}
```

With this code it works on Android what I want to achieve (not the the folder `android_asset/www/phoneplugin` is the `www` from my "pluginized" Ionic App. With this I can just open my "pluginized" App using a button to call my `start` method and it works perfectly, a splash screen shows up and then the App works (I really dislike this but it's what my bosses wants, so idc).

Now my problem comes with iOS. I have no idea about Swift and I am just getting to the "pluginized" App's splash screen and then the pluginized App closes.

This is what I have so far but idk how to complete it or idk if it's right and the problem is something else:

@objc(PhonePlugin)
class PhonePlugin : CDVPlugin {

```
@objc(start:)
func start(_ command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {

    let json = try? JSON(data: jsonData)
    let authToken = json["token"]
    let key = json["secret_key"]

    let vc = CDVViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

    vc.startPage = "phoneplugin/index.html"

    let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController

    rootVC?.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    rootVC?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@objc(finish:)
func finish(_ command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
    let rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    rootVC?.presentedViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}
```

}

My `plugin.xml` incase it's needed is the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="ionic-phone-plugin" version="1.0.0" 
    xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <name>PhonePlugin</name>

    <js-module name="PhonePlugin" src="www/PhonePlugin.js">
        <clobbers target="window.cordova.plugins.PhonePlugin" />
    </js-module>

    <engines>
        <engine name="cordova" version=">=6.5.0" />
    </engines>

    <asset src="src/www" target="phoneplugin" />
    <dependency id="cordova-android-support-gradle-release" version="2.1.0" />
    <dependency id="cordova-android-play-services-gradle-release" version="3.0.0" />
    <dependency id="cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release" version="3.0.0" />
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-bluetooth-serial" version="0.4.7" />
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-geolocation" version="4.0.1" />
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-insomnia" version="4.3.0" />
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-network-information" version="2.0.1" />
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy" version="2.2.3" />
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-tts" version="0.2.3" />
    <dependency id="cordova.plugins.diagnostic" version="4.0.9" />
    <dependency id="cordova-sqlite-storage" version="2.3.3" />
    <dependency id="cordova-open-native-settings" version="1.5.2" />
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-statusbar" version="2.4.2" />
    <dependency id="situm-cordova-plugin-official" version="1.14.2" />
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-screen-orientation" version="3.0.1" />
    <dependency id="cordova-plugin-add-swift-support" version="1.7.2"/>

    <platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
            <feature name="PhonePlugin">
                <param name="android-package" value="com.test.phoneplugin.PhonePlugin" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>


        <config-file target="AndroidManifest.xml" parent="/manifest/application">
            <activity android:name="com.test.phoneplugin.PhonePluginActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="src/android/com/test/phoneplugin/PhonePlugin.java" target-dir="src/com/test/phoneplugin" />
        <source-file src="src/android/com/test/phoneplugin/PhoneActivity.java" target-dir="src/com/test/phoneplugin" />
    </platform>


    <platform name="ios">
        <config-file parent="/*" target="config.xml">
            <feature name="PhonePlugin">
                <param name="ios-package" value="PhonePlugin" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>

        <source-file src="src/ios/PhonePlugin.swift" />
    </platform>

</plugin>
```

The `config.xml` where I am trying to install this pluginized App is this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="io.ionic.adadadasasdfffgg" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>MyApp</name>
    <description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
    <author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <preference name="ScrollEnabled" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.4.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="2.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="5.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^4.0.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" spec="^2.0.5" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-googlemaps" spec="~2.4.4">
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_IOS" value="AIzaSyBpAjztTxH4ldWJBOWiJXvRZZsBVw0y_oI" />
        <variable name="API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID" value="AIzaSyD3RIddnImiOjtE0ep8mV6FrXEEcc6Uaz8" />
        <variable name="LOCATION_WHEN_IN_USE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app wants to get your location while this app runs only." />
        <variable name="LOCATION_ALWAYS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="This app wants to get your location always, even this app runs in background." />
        <variable name="PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION" value="15.0.1" />
        <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION" value="27.+" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="ionic-phone-plugin" spec="/Users/macbookairdt/Desktop/test/PhonePlugin" />
    <engine name="browser" spec="~5.0.4" />
    <engine name="android" spec="~7.1.4" />
</widget>
```

Anybody has an idea of why it's not working?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using:

```
vc.startPage = "file:///phoneplugin/index.html"
```